# How much certainty should exist for an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Obviously there are varying degrees of this all over the site, ranging from "I'm 100% sure of this, I've test this thoroughly" to "Maybe this or that". At what level of certainty should an answer be posted?

Obvious a WAG is not an answer, but if the question relates to experience where the answerer has a high confidence that they are correct, should that answer be posted, letting the community upvote/downvote to provide corroboration or rejection of that experience? In some cases in the past I've used comments to do this, perhaps a suggestion that may or may not resolve the question, but I've also know that comments should not be used for answers. Just looking for some feedback on this issue.

Comment: What does WAG mean?

Comment: @Whymarrh [Wild-ass guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Wild-Ass_Guess). That's somewhere between "no idea at all" and "might be something in that ballpark, maybe".

Comment: The answerer doesn't need to be 100% certain of the answer, but the answer should be written as if they were. If the answer is incorrect, hopefully the community will let them know in the form of swift downvotes.

Comment: Sorry @Whymarrh, I've used and heard that used so often I took it for universal :)

Answer (score 9):

If your coworker came to you with the same question, how would you respond to them? You might choose to tell them, "sorry, I have an idea about this, but I'm not confident in my experience."

I'd equate that with a comment. You don't want to be the definitive source, but you very much want to contribute, because you honestly believe it would be helpful. Over time, you might find yourself converting the comment into a full-blown answer because of general peer acceptance.

You might be pretty certain of your answer. In that case, put your rep on the line. Worse case, you'll have negative responses pointing out why your approach isn't a good one. At least you'll learn something, and the OP will, too! If necessary, you can always delete the answer. But, if you genuinely think that you could be correct (because you've used that approach before), then step forward.

If I'm not sure what the OP is asking, or not at least mostly sure I'm correct, I tend to take the approach of commenting. Sure, someone may answer the question with exactly what you were thinking, but it shouldn't be about the rep.

**Edit**

As Deduplicator mentioned, you may find yourself going back-and-forth in comments, anyway. Often, you'll find that it isn't that you don't know the answer to the OP's question - it's that the OP hasn't included enough content to be able to be answerable. If you (and others) don't fully understand the question, there's no harm in asking the OP for more clarification via comments, and that may in turn generate an answer by getting the OP to think it through...

Comment: You might want to add that the uncertainty might originate from the question missing crucial detail. Which means it should be clarified (and might need closing in the interim), and *then* answered.

Comment: @Deduplicator Good call - done.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the question a bit.  If the question is very clear and all the details are there, there should be more confidence in the answer.  For example, if the question was "Why am I getting this compile error *all relevant code here*", I would expect someone to be fairly confident about what is wrong, mostly because you should be able to copy the code and run the compiler.

On the other hand, as the question and the details get muddier, I am fine with much less confidence in the answer.  If I saw the question

> *"I'm trying to install FooBonger on my system and every time I get a Squitcherwall exception.  I've googled it and tried slapping the dingleberry and whomping the goosenflopper.  How can I fix this?"*

Since the question is less clear and there is really no way to replicate their machine. it becomes far harder to say "this is definitely your problem, fix it like this".

TL/DR: I would expect more confidence in answers where the problem is more easily reproducible for the answerer.

Comment: Excellent answer, very good point, and great humor.. (laughed out loud while reading)